# SignalR initialising the connection on page refresh

Tags: javascript, signalr

the code :

```
  $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
    chat.server.connectclient(UserID, UserName);
  });
```

why on every page refresh signalR access connectClient function ? and  can i prevent that to make it accessed just once ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On every page refresh, the existing connection will be disconnected and a new one would be established. That is why the hub.start() & connectClient functions are called. You cannot change this behavior.

Comment: in my code i am sending a notification to notify other users that the current user is online but because of this behavior my notification is displayed several time if the user refresh the page instead of displaying just one time when the user is online